# Fedex how to set preferred currency in PHP

Tags: php, fedex

Fedex seems to have very intuitive documentation and no code samples (besides the downloaded modules). I want to change the currency for the rates from fedex. In documentation/XML file I have found something like preferredCurrency. Similar to other attributes I'm trying to set it like this:

```
if($var == 'preferredcurrency') Return 'HUF';
```

but this is totally ignored (I tried also PreferredCurrency) and the returned rate is always $USD. Anyone is familiar with FEDEX API and can help?

UPDATE:

It's basically about requesting and receiving response. I have some function where I set parameters like:

```
function getProperty($var){
if($var == 'shipper') Return array(
        'Contact' => array(
            'PersonName' => 'Sender Name',
            'CompanyName' => 'Sender Company Name',
            'PhoneNumber' => '1234567890'
        ),
        'Address' => array(
            'StreetLines' => array('Address Line 1'),
            'City' => 'SomeCity',
            'StateOrProvinceCode' => 'SomeState',
            'PostalCode' => '3434343',
            'CountryCode' => 'US',
            'Residential' => 1
        )
    );
}
```

and then in another file a request to fedex is made, like :

```
$request['RequestedShipment']['Shipper'] = array(
    'Address'=>getProperty('address1')
);
```

All of this values are defined in an XML file, I'm trying to get rate including CurrencyExchangeRate like this:

```
$request['CurrencyExchangeRate'] = array(
    'FromCurrency' => array('USD'),
    'IntoCurrency' => array('HUF'),
    'Rate' => array(1.0)
);
```

But this request is ignored and I don't know why.

Comment: Please provide more code.

Comment: Paste the part of the code that uses this variable.

Comment: A quick glance at a few FedEx docs I was able to find show `PreferredCurrency` in several places; perhaps the if-statement is failing due to case-sensitivity? Like @McCormick32 said, hard to tell without seeing more code, especially not knowing what `$var` is.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you just have a misssing Element. The Docs are here: [Shipment Docs](https://www.fedex.com/us/developer/WebHelp/ws/2014/dvg/WS_DVG_WebHelp/index.htm#3__VACS___CountryService.htm).

`$request['RequestedShipment']['PreferredCurrency'] = 'HUF'` and
`$request['RequestedShipment']['RateRequestTypes'] = 'PREFERRED'`